# What's the deal with Halo and Spark in Flex 4?

Tags: apache-flex, flex-spark, halo

I used Flex 2/3 for a couple of years and have just come back to it, upgrading to Flex 4. I'm seeing some references to Halo and Spark themes but I never got into themes in my previous work so I'm a bit confused what's going on. Am I correct that Halo was the default theme, or is this all new?

Also, I took a simple Flex 3 MXML and tried to make it work in Flex4:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
    layout="absolute" borderStyle="none" borderColor="#000000" cornerRadius="0" 
    backgroundGradientAlphas="[1.0, 1.0]" backgroundGradientColors="[#000000, #FF0000]"
    width="800" height="600"
    frameRate="20">
</mx:Application>
```

But I get errors, like "**Error: The style 'backgroundGradientColors' is only supported by type 'mx.core.Application' with the theme(s) 'halo'.**"

I tried a few things but each one introduced its own errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flex 4 introduced a new component architecture, called "Spark".  "Halo" refers to the Flex 3 component architecture.

- [an overview of Spark vs Halo components](http://unitedmindset.com/jonbcampos/2009/07/02/flex-4-spark-skinning/)
- [instructions to use Halo theme in a project](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/07/14/using-the-halo-theme-in-flex-4/) (which is what you need to make your example compile)

Comment: So Spark is not an alternate theme, but a new approach - that suggests I'd be better using Spark in my Flex 4 application if it's not a big amount of work, right?

Comment: That's right.  You should focus on the spark UI components for new projects.

Comment: Disagree. You should choose based on the project requirements. Sometimes Spark makes things (which were simple in Halo) needlessly more complicated. Spark is better if you're doing heavy UI skinning & customization. If you don't do custom skin work, but want something nicer looking than Spark's boring default look, Halo is a nice alternative. Our users tend to like Halo UIs better than Spark UIs, which look like a step back to some (out of the box).